# How is my macro that calculates factorial not working in excel

Tags: excel, vba, factorial

[image]

Please help me understand why I am getting a #VALUE! error in Excel using the following UDF in VBA?

I looked up this VBA code which is supposed to calculate factorial for numbers of any size including those larger than 170 which is my specific interest:

```
Function FactorialUsingForLoop(val As Long) As Long
    Dim uni_input As Long, xy_Factorial As Long
    Let xy_Factorial = 1
    For uni_input = 1 To val
        xy_Factorial = xy_Factorial * uni_input
    Next
    FactorialUsingForLoop = xy_Factorial
End Function
```

Note a copy of my worksheet. The triangle says: a value in the formula is of a wrong data type. I have eliminated extra spaces, the format is Numbers!

Thanks!

Comment: All of your factorial under 10 are working. Think about what the value of 459! Would look like and consider how you would handle inputs whose calculations are larger than excel can compute. Your code is right, your just accepting inputs that are too large to compute.

Comment: The maximum of the `Long` data type is about 2*10^9. Your errors are for larger results. Try Double, Decimal or LongLong

Comment: Excel can only handle up to 15 digits of precision - if you try anything larger the 16th, 17th, etc digits will all be zeros.

Comment: @Tim Williams, your answer applies to Excel Cell values that use double precision floating point,  but not to this VBA code which is working with Longs.  Longs only have 9+ digits of precision and because they are integer calculation types will suffer Overflow when calculating larger numbers which Excel traps and returns as #Value errors.

Comment: @ChrisMaurer - my comment was intended as a follow-on to the previous two comments  - I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the "Multiply" function from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications/Big_Number_Arithmetic_with_Strings#The_VBA_String_Math_Module you can perform the factorial on the string representation of the numbers:

```
Function FactString(n As Long) As String
    Dim i As Long, s
    s = "1"
    For i = 2 To n
        s = Multiply(s, CStr(i)) 'see link above
    Next i
    FactString = s 'return as text
End Function
```

FYI `FactString(459)` is 1025 digits.  Not sure what you could usefully do with the output though?

14485403354484377321946598467762747909890903376354418365375845955625396614008248762435334105235580367713111676386354517817732216317813131627739098804735552619387696361000728350823018080878612362369972102024834022677419331190003646581872203634520283130933793877130922404915890229584207088813666362515804443836956427867939234940645305786761788625294812604394194311811648253226441130486116296174698732284230693452530000613019235681414109884129686923390790591493053092840252338650743843979540442934522441499732761419205481441571729238180772206283267561602205068359377969242866767033627224184350824364701713347358540970587316052075568936320882958156270299294847780095880319469432857013405651004619680268495021224607907646943617462020856149988907272090333825938106785197889156789076323307207860239236383751068288278126756115213803211186543060092701556735081943005710263322762703394271852483534078236589862938081272791040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

**EDIT** - just noticed that link of methods does include a factorial method:

`Function Factorial(ByVal sA As String) As String`

Comment: Thanks for looking further into this. Here's what I attempted to do in order to build my UDF:
Public Function Multiply(ByVal sA As String, ByVal sB As String) As String
End Function
Function FactString(n As Long) As String Dim i As Long, s s = "1" For i = 2 To n s = Multiply(s, CStr(i)) Next i FactString = s End Function Sub New_factorial()
End Sub
On to my worksheet, I type "=FactString(D2)" to invoke the function. This returns a blank cell!! Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: By the way, to answer you earlier Q as to what the use of this would be, I'm only trying to calculate the separate components of the Log Likelihood function found in the middle of page here:    https://real-statistics.com/poisson-regression/poisson-regression-basic-concepts/ . So, won't really need these large factorials directly!! You might have a thought on this?! In any case I appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Please edit your question if you have additional info to add - it's too difficult to follow in comments. Thanks

Comment: it looks like it should work with the Multiply() and Factorial functions in the link but unfortunately I was not able to get it to work for me. Will have to look into an alternative model or leave out my few data points!! Thanks again!

Comment: It does work for (it returns the correct "number string" for the input's factorial) but you can't really do anything useful with the output....

Comment: I agree, although, my final goal was to reconstruct the different components in a Poisson distribution (including the factorial) so in the end would be looking at the log of the factorial and even then being subtracted from another large number! So, practically the end result from the Poisson formula should be in the hundreds. Thanks again for the contributions. I’ll post a response later that I have looked up and it involves approximating large factorial components with the Sterling formula.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Double` instead of `Long`, I just tried and these are the values for the first numbers up to 50 (with an increase of 5):

[image]

Comment: If you use the `Decimal` data type you can get non-error values from the UDF for `n<28`. If you use the `FACT` worksheet function, you can have `n<171` before overflowing. You will only have 15 digits precision, however.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and answers. Unfortunately, the large number factorials ( such as 459!) appear to yield much larger number than Excel can handle in precision digits regardless of the data type Long or even Double. In this case have I have to review my other options for these data points as @Jesse Sealand suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to calculate the factorial of a large number (perhaps as part of a formula such as in Poisson distribution) you may consider the following approximation:

Stirling’s formula. Stirling’s formula states that

x! ≈ √(2 * π * x) * (x / e)^x

Also, for large number calculations, XNumber, a free Excel Add-In worked great!!